# Quality travel clothesline that is easy to hook on shower stalls?

Tags: tips-and-tricks, gear, clothing, laundry

I have the [Rick Steves clothesline](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0009PCTUU) which just has Velcro/loops at the ends:

[image: clothesline]

However, I will most certainly be travelling with shower stall access for the next few months and I want to be able to just hook wet clothes across the shower stall. Which of the clotheslines available can most definitely fit on a shower stall frame? [Metal frames too (2 inch thickness perhaps) and not just thin glass stalls]. All the hooks I see seem really small at the ends...perhaps there is a line available  with a hook for the stall and a loop end to tie around the showerhead?

I can't determine which  brand has hooks that are big enough. I suppose most people will use suction but I don't like suction at all. Anyone know which clothesline fits this situation? Quality and efficiency over price. I like the [Sea to Summit one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000T28X4E) since it's tiny but it's too complicated and long just put across a stall.

Comment: Have you considered taking a handful of carabiners and hooks to which you can attach your existing clothesline, rather than buying a new clothesline with different ends?

Comment: Sounds brilliant. But I'm not familiar with exactly how carabiners work...I just associate them with rock climbking or bikes :-) ...which types exactly? Anythng lightweight with a good grasp on glass etc. Will a hook end have to be stitched on?

Comment: The kind kids use to attach keys or water bottles to backpacks or belt loops, not the climbing ones. Go to Canadian Tire and they should have them near the cash. Then go check out hook ends on the hardware and housewares section. You should take 3 or 4 different ends since you don't know what you'll be facing. With luck you can just wrap the Velcro round the hook. A handful of hair elastics might also be useful. Or poke a hook through the twisted strands at one end - or the middle if the line is too loose.

Comment: @Kate Gregory:  Oh, the work... :-)

Answer (score 3):

I spent two weeks traveling in September using a [Travelon clothes line](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007712D4Q) and really liked it. It came with suction cups which were ok, but I ended up hooking it directly to objects or looping it back on itself a lot. I also had some short bungee cords that I used to extend it a few times.

Comment: How big is the hook (the circumference)? Never seen it in person.

Comment: I don't have it with me but I'd say it's about 1x1.5inches. Not a huge hook but enough to run wire/bungie cords/etc through. Sorry that I don't have more details.